# python & mysql, Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have this code:

```
my_cursor = my_db.cursor()

def Insert_object(Title, Details, Amount):
    sql_command = 'INSERT INTO income (title, details, amount) VALUES (%s, %s, %d)'
    values = (Title, Details, Amount)
    my_cursor.executemany(sql_command, values)
    my_db.commit()


Insert_object('Chips', 'Chili', 12)
```

but it throws the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters
```

Comment: Why do you need `executemany`? You try to insert only one row.

Answer (score 0):

In [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) it says that the second argument of `executemany` function is a list of tuples. Try changing `values` so that it is a list that contains a single tuple.

```
values = [(Title, Details, Amount)]
my_cursor.executemany(sql_command, values)
```

Comment: [execute](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) can work as well.